# Checking if the datetime in the column is not more than 1 hour old

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js

How to check if a particular column say `modified` is not more than 1 hour old?

```
MessageModel.findAll({
        where : {
            status : Constant.PROCESSING,
            modified : {
                // ?? //
            }
        }
    });
```

How do I write the condition using sequelize?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the greater-than-or-equal-to syntax ($gte) like this:

```
modified : { $lte: new Date(Date.now() - 60*60*1000) }
```